# Can KLM Checked-in baggage be **not suitcase**?

Tags: air-travel, regulations, klm, check-in

Can KLM checked-in baggage be **not suitcase** ?

I've found that in rules it's called "suitcase":

> Check-in baggage: 1 suitcase* of max. 23 kg / 50 lbs

So far I was mostly flying with "Star Alliance" airlines and always with bag. Bag from flexible material, fitting size, with strong back and handle like those:

[image: Picture of check-in lauggage not suitcase from flexible material with strong back]

(or maybe this [image: Picture of check-in lauggage not suitcase from flexible material with strong back] )

References:

From : [Your baggage - KLM](http://www.klm.com/travel/ph_en/prepare_for_travel/baggage/baggage_allowance/index.htm)

> Check-in baggage: 1 suitcase* of max. 23 kg / 50 lbs

(...)

> Sizes
>
> - Each suitcase may measure max. 158 cm / 62 in (l + w + h).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Special baggage](http://www.klm.com/travel/ca_en/prepare_for_travel/baggage/exceptional_baggage/index.htm#p11)

> You can bring other types of sports equipment and other items instead of a suitcase or instead of an extra suitcase bought in advance, if:
>
> Max. 158 cm / 62 in (l + w + h)
>
> Max. 23 kg / 50.5 lbs in Economy Class
>
> Max. 32 kg / 70.5 lbs in Business Class

Also, I myself have checked in cardboard boxes with various airlines (also see the [Balikbayan box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balikbayan_box)) and there was no problem. It doesn't matter much what you check in as long as it is not too large -- and if it's too large, the airline will ask you to pay for it and then pay more to the airport(s) to handle the problem so you can still check it in.

Comment: Thanks all! I've found that they have US number which worked during our evening, and they confirmed that reasonably looking like above works as long as fits dimensions and weight :)